# make column calculation in teradata safe

Tags: teradata

Let us say I have this contrived/simplified sql:

```
SELECT
    Column1/Column2                
FROM SomeTable;
```

where Column2 could be 0 resulting in a div by zero and thus the whole query falling over. I could do something like this:

```
SELECT
    Column1/Column2                
FROM SomeTable
where Column2 <> 0;
```

or use a COALESCE, CASE statement etc. The challenge I have is that the 'formula' e.g. Column1/Column2 can be dynamic (no danger of sql injection).

Ideally, I would like to wrap the 'computed column's' calculation in some kind of try catch and return -9999 for any failed calculation and otherwise the result of the calculation. I hope this makes sense. If so, can this be achieved somehow?

Comment: For the immediate example, NULLIFZERO(Column2) would avoid a divide by zero error. How is this SQL being contrived? In a stored procedure, you have some additional flexibility to trap errors and handle them accordingly. Macros and regular SQL, less so.

Comment: I could create a sql query for each column. I could then capture an exception in C# in my case. However, I would like to create several computed columns in one query to avoid IO: Column1/Column2, (Column2/Column3)*10.3, etc. Sorry I did not mention this in the question - tried to keep it simple.

Comment: Column1/NULLIFZERO(Column2), (Column2/NULLIFZERO(Column3))*10.3 - Each operation will yield NULL if divisor is zero. Am I missing something in your question or comment?

Comment: Sorry - there was more context to this but and existing answer was deleted. The 'formula' like Column1/Column2 are dynamically created and could also be Column1 + Log(Column2). If Column2 is zero in the latter example, it results in infinity another pronlem, Ideally I would like to put a 'try/catch' around each formula. Not sure if this is possible in teradata.